# How to sort 3 digit versions with unix sort

Tags: sorting

I have a file of software versions of the form `a.b.c` where `a`, `b`, and `c` are integers.  For example

```
2.10.1
1.10.3
10.4.9
1.9.10 
1.2.30
```

I have tried:

```
sort -k 1n -k1,3 -t $'.' versions
```

And this works but only on the first column.   How do I specify sub-sorting on column 2 and 3?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This sorts your mentioned version numbers right. The separator is set to `.`, the comparison is numerically by `-n` and the order is first from column 1 to 1`-k 1,1`, second from column 2 to 2 `-k 2,2` and third from column 3 to 3 `-k 3,3`.

```
$ echo '2.10.1
1.10.3
10.4.9
1.9.10
1.2.30' | sort -t '.' -n -k 1,1 -k 2,2 -k 3,3

1.2.30
1.9.10
1.10.3
2.10.1
10.4.9
```

Comment: Awesome, thanks, I had come up with some unwieldy cmd line perl.  Nice and clean Matthias, cheers.